# Orange3 widget menu items are disabled

Tags: orange

I was wondering why the items in the top "Widget" menu of a freshly installed Orange3 installation are disabled.

Is there some setting that I need to enable in order to be able to open widgets? There seems to be nothing in the documentation that mentions this particular menu items and what it does.

Thanks,

Ralph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are options to work with a selected widget. They are disabled when no widget is selected at the workspace. So if you want to use them first place any widget at the workspace. When you single click at the widget on the workspace you will see that those options become enabled.